# Class methods for models with access to store

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-cli

I have been battling this issue for a while now.

In my Ember app (using ember-cli) I have a model that I would like to attach some class methods for.

I would like to be able to call from my controllers Model.allWithIssues to find all of the model instances that have registered issues.

To achive that, I have added a method using the following code:

```
Model.reopenClass({
    allWithIssues: function () { ... }
})
```

My problem is, I don't have access to the data store from inside the model.

I have tried in many different ways inject store:main to the model but with no luck. 
One answer here even claimed there is no way to inject to a model, while others suggested  ways to achieve DI into models that simply didn't work.

Is my approach completely wrong? Should I keep this logic in a separated class?

**EDIT:**

The solutions I had in mind are:

- Make a generic controller that includes this methods and have all of the controllers that need this method extend it.
- Some sort of mixin
- Make a "repository" class, working as an abstraction layer between the controllers and the store.

I'm still not sure which route is the best to go in, but all of those seem too robust for something as simple as this.

Comment: Maybe add the method to a type-specific adaptor? I dont think its correct to have this logic in the *model*, models are just data representation.

Comment: @Asgaroth

I understand that the model should only have dry data in it and no logic, but I can't think of any other place to put this sort of reusable logic in.

I don't think the adapter is the correct place as it's suppose to be the communication layer to my understanding.

I would just put in as a controller method, but it is used in different controllers.

Iv'e edited the main question with possible solution I have in mind.

Comment: Any reason not to inject this directly on the `store`? `Application.register('...'); Application.inject('store',...);` should work... You can then call `this.get('store').allBlahWithIssues()`

Comment: @thriqon, That's an interesting solution that will in fact solve the problem. But it's not suppose to be the concern of the data store to handle logic of a specific model filtration.

Comment: Well, in fact it does filtering, e.g. if you call `.filter()` or `.query()`. So I'd consider it an acceptable solution.

Answer (score 0):

Controller is not the right place either, unless you have all models loaded, and what you do its a computed propert.

the model's hook in a router would be a better place, its whitin its responsibilities of an adapter to loa data, deserialize it, and provide you with model instances.

Or you can create a service, that lives in you /lib folder, register it with the CI, and inject the store to it. depends on your use case.

Comment: And what about code reuse? 

What if I want to call this method in more than one place? 

A service will solve this problem, but it's a very robust solution for a very easy problem.